# Can geolocation accept non geolocation GPS Lat & Lon data?

Tags: geolocation

Can non geolocation be passed to the geolocation function;

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition();
```

In a off line situation (network or cellular) can I pass real-time live GPS Lat & Lon coordinates transmitted via LoRa radios and an ESP32 micro to each other to then displayed on our local OSM app on our iPhones?